# How to spawn enemy at random intervals?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using EnemyScript to move the enemy towards the player and killing the player, but I'm unable to spawn it randomly in code. I am currently spawning it directly through screen by placing the prefab on the scene.

Here is my EnemyScript

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyScript : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform target;
public float speed = 2f;

void Update ()
{
    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
}


void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D otherCollider)
{
    PlayerControl shot = otherCollider.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerControl>();
    if (shot != null)
    {
        Destroy(shot.gameObject); 
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use something similar to this:

```
public GameObject myObj;

void Start () 
{
    enemy = GameObject.Find("enemy");
    InvokeRepeating("SpawnEnemy", 1.6F, 1F);                
}

public void SpawnEnemy() 
{       

    Vector3 position = new Vector3(Random.Range(35.0F, 40.0F), Random.Range(-4F, 2F), 0);       
    Instantiate(myObj, position, Quaternion.identity);

}
```

in the InvokeRepeating call you could possibly add  the random range there also instead of a timed instantiate.  This example is just a snippet of some prototype code i did a while ago, it may not suit your needs directly but hopefully will give you a general idea on what to do.

EDIT: to make sense, put this into a blank object somewhere in your scene, dont attach this to the actual enemy.

Comment: its aint spawning anything on the screen ,i set the enemy image to the game object.,but still no luck

Comment: you going to have to edit this to suit your needs, like i said this is a snippet of a similar thing,  Gameobject is just a global variable of a GameObject

Comment: if i remember correctly all you need to do is attach this script to your prefab object, this specific script will spawn and "enemy" at certain intervals, for your case you may need to tweak this for a more randomized spawner

Comment: also remember this is for 3d, im using vector3, so again you need to change to a vector2 and fiddle with the numbers so they spawn on screen and not somewhere 30 miles away at random

Comment: tweaked it with game objects but still not single enemy spawn

Comment: left of the editor do you see the enemy being created, only you cant see them on screen? are there any errors?  try putting debug logs in there such as Debug.Log("got this far woot")

Comment: i programmed it like this.      
public GameObject enemyPrefab;
 public float numEnemies;
 public float xMin = 20F;
 public float xMax = 85F;
 public float yMin = 3.5F;
 public float yMax = -4.5F;

 void Start () {

  for (int i=0; i< numEnemies; i++) {
   Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(Random.Range(xMin,xMax),Random.Range(yMin,yMax),0);
   GameObject enemy = Instantiate(enemyPrefab,newPos,Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
  }
 }

Answer (score 0):

i programmed it like this.

```
public GameObject enemyPrefab;
public float numEnemies;
public float xMin = 20F;
public float xMax = 85F;
public float yMin = 3.5F;
public float yMax = -4.5F;

void Start () {

    for (int i=0; i< numEnemies; i++) {
        Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(Random.Range(xMin,xMax),Random.Range(yMin,yMax),0);
        GameObject enemy = Instantiate(enemyPrefab,newPos,Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, but wont that simply loop insanely fast thus spawn enemy's extremely fast?

Comment: but atleast a single enemy should spawn?right,because i already have built a update function to make it move towards the player.i just need to spawn it through code

Comment: when you run the game what happens? left of the scene where you see your gameobjects listed int eh explorer you should see things being created/destroyed, do you see enemys being created there?

Comment: no there is not a single enemy anywhere.just my player is there.the enemy aren't spawning from the right side of the screen and no where near.

Comment: i dont mean there position in the scene viewer, i mean in unity below you have your debug log, to the right you have properties and to the left you have a list of all your objects, your player etc etc, when you run the game do you see that list change at all?

Comment: there are 4 things in total,1)Main Camera,2)background,3)player,4)shoot(clone),the shoot(clone) is for the shooting and it comes when we start shooting and the background contains just a single image

Comment: ok so when you run the tha game that list doesnt change at all?

Comment: ok, this may sound silly, you do have the script attached to some object dont you? as in you didnt just bang this code into the enemy class?

Comment: yes everything is so far attached.,as per their functionality.

Comment: correct me if im wrong, but i have a feeling you have attached this code into your enemy class, is this correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65835/discussion-between-steven-smith-and-safwan).

Answer (score 0):

This will spawn a random number of enemies, at random locations, after random periods of time, all adjustable in the Inspector.

```
public float minTime = 1;
public float maxTime = 3;
public int minSpawn = 1;
public int maxSpawn = 4;
public Bounds spawnArea; //set these bounds in the inspector
public GameObject enemyPrefab;

private spawnTimer = 0;

Vector3 randomWithinBounds(Bounds r) {
    return new Vector3(
        Random.Range(r.min.x, r.max.x),
        Random.Range(r.min.y, r.max.y),
        Random.Range(r.min.z, r.max.z));
}

void Update() {
    spawnTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
    if(spawnTimer <= 0) {
        spawnTimer += Random.Range(minTime, maxTime);
        int randomSpawnCount = Random.Range(minSpawn, maxSpawn);
        for(int i = 0; i < randomSpawnCount; i++) {
            Instantiate(transform.transformPoint(enemyPrefab), randomWithinBounds(spawnArea), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}

//bonus: this will show you the spawn area in the editor

void OnDrawGizmos() {
    Gizmos.matrix = transform.localToWorldMatrix;
    Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
    Gizmos.drawWireCube(spawnArea.center, spawnArea.size);
}
```

People on here seem to like using coroutines for time delays, but I personally prefer to track my own timers in Update() to maximize control and predictability.